# Using append with member predicate

Tags: list, prolog, append

I want to know how I can implement append into the member predicate.

I have this for members

```
member2(X, [X|T]).
member2(X, [H|T]) :-  member2(X,T).
```

How could I implement append into this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the implementation of the `append/3` predicate:

```
append([],X,X).
append([H|T],X,[H|S]) :- append(T,X,S).
```

You can define `member/2` predicate using `append/3` as follows

```
member(X,L) :- append(_,[X|_],L).
```

where `append(_,[X|_],L)` splits the list `L` of all possible forms (by reevaluation) and the member `X` unifies with the head of the second list `[X|_]`.